# Jquery Thumbnail Pager with Captions?

Tags: jquery, pager

I know there has to be an easy solution for this!

http://procollage.com/site10/wall-of-fame/favs-cycle.html

I have a thumbnail image pager, I just want each slide to have a description underneath the large photo. It can be done, right? Help please?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('#slideshow').before('<ul id="nav">').cycle({
        fx:     'fade',
        speed:  'slow',
        timeout: 0,
        pager:  '#nav',
        pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx, slide) {
            var src = $('img',slide).attr('src');
            return '<li><a href="#"><img src="' + src + '" width="50" height="50" /></a></li>';
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you create a list of links. Each link corresponds to a panel below. The panels are absolutely-positioned one on top of the other. When you click a link, it fades out all non-corresponding panels, and shows its own.

Example: http://jsbin.com/ubebo/2/edit

Comment: Firstly, THANK YOU for this as it does work. If i'm going to have 30 or so samples on that page, there's gonna be alot of 'panels'. There has to be a javascript function that I can use with the pager, no? Like an 'after' callback. I just have NO IDEA how to code it.

Again, thank you and any more help is GREATLY appreciated.